# Responsive menú closes too fast (meet-gavern template)

Tags: templates, responsive-design

I just created my first web page using a responsive template (meet-gavern).
I like it alot... But the responsive menu seen from my iPhone closes (dissapear) way too fast.
I am a beginner at web design and 0 knowledge of programming. It must be some quick fix, but i have no idea where to start...
Any help please? 
Web: lasrejasopenclub.com

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of code in your stylesheet that creates this transition. In “bootstrap.css” see *line 2489*: The `transition: height .35s ease;` property is applied to the `.collapse` class.

If you change `.35s` to a larger number, the menu will not disappear as quickly. Try using `1s` to see it take a 1 second.

Note: Rather than directly editing “bootstrap.css”, you may want to simply include this rule in your own CSS file:

```
.collapse {
    -webkit-transition: height 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: height 1s ease;
    -o-transition: height 1s ease;
    transition: height 1s ease;
}
```

Obviously you can play with different numbers and easing properties to get it how you want. But this is the place to start. (Learn more about transitions here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Comment: If you have a minute and you can let me know whether or not this suggestion works for you, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!